# POST unchecked checkboxes with values to Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, checkbox

This is a common topic but in this particular use-case I have not been able to find a solution. I have a dynamic number of checkboxes in a form which is being submitted to a Node.js server. My checkboxes look like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='ingredient[num]' value='off' /> //not currently in use, see below
<input type='checkbox' name='ingredient[num]' checked />
```

When all checkboxes are checked, the server receives something that looks like this (after req.body.ingredient):

```
{ num: ['on','on','on'] }
```

When there are some or all checkboxes unchecked, I want it to receive something like this, with the same number of values:

```
{num: ['on','off','off'] }
```

I have tried using a hidden input with value='off' before and after my checkboxes and this hasn't worked. The server receives both 'on' and 'off' values when checked. I've also tried a JavaScript workaround (below) and I haven't gotten it to work. Any ideas?

```
<script>
let form = document.getElementById('addIngredients');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)');
    boxes.forEach(function(box) {
        box.setAttribute('value', 'off');
    });

    form.submit();
})
</script>
```

**EDIT: This is not like the suggested duplicate question. Body parser does not seem to be grouping checked boxes as arrays when using a hidden input. For example, with three boxes, all checked, the server is receiving `[ 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on' ]`**

Comment: The hidden input thing usually works. What did your HTML look like? Please show both the hidden input and the checkbox

Comment: @Phil It looked like `[input type='hidden' name='ingredient[num]' value='off' />`

Comment: Code goes in your question, not in the comments. Also, what data do you get when submitted?

Comment: @Phil I get 'on' when checked, nothing when unchecked.